# В профилях сотрудников теперь есть индикатор «Сотрудник»

Tags: обсуждение, профиль-участника

[С сегодняшнего дня](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331654/260198) все учётные записи сотрудников будут иметь бейджик «Сотрудник» рядом с их именем в профиле (пока что [перевёл](https://ru.traducir.win/string/13009) как "Сотрудник", можете предложить свой вариант в ответах).

> [image: Профиль сотрудника]

Воспользовались существующим дизайном для рейтинга «лучшие n% за всё время», который фактически перевернули, чтобы выделиться среди других. Кроме того, обновили метку модератора, чтобы была позаметнее.

---

### Устранение путаницы

Была замечена общая проблема как для пользователей, так и для сотрудников - сотрудникам часто приходится публиковать ответы на мета-сайтах, чтобы объяснить, как работает тот или иной инструмент или реагировать на репорты о багах. Это отличная возможность пообщаться, но иногда отсутствие индикатора у сотрудника делает эти взаимодействия более сложными.

Вы можете спросить: «А как же ромбы?». И в некоторых случаях вы были бы правы. Основная цель ромбов - указать модераторов на сайте. Это пользователи, не являющиеся сотрудниками, но имеющие в своём распоряжении дополнительные инструменты и особый доступ к информации. Ранее выдавали их сотрудникам, теперь же эти возможности предоставляются только определённым типам сотрудников, которым необходим доступ к этим инструментам - как правило, разработчикам и управляющим сообществ.

Таким образом, остальные члены команды упоминали свой статус в разделах «обо мне». Это просто не приемлемый вариант. Помимо того, что довольно легко забыть, это на самом деле не являлось доказательством принадлежности к команде SE. Любой может отредактировать свой профиль, заявив, что он часть персонала.

Добавление такого индикатора не оригинальная идея. Сообщество годами просило, чтобы сотрудники как-то выделялись:

- [Keep "Employee" on the profile of SE employees on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161197/260198).
- [Can we have a square or triangle or heart or *something* after employees' names?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310518/260198)
- [Split visualization of employee and moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341657/1991579).

Если у вас есть какие-то вопросы/предложения, можете написать в ответах. И лучше сразу в [оригинальном посте](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331654/260198).

Comment: Скрин бы надо из приватного режима сделать лучше. Меньше модераторского шлака :) И линк на профиль можно будет добавить. Вообще, при таком раскладе на странице [Участники](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users) хорошо бы новую вкладку добавить.

Comment: А чего не шестигранник к имени?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ done.

Comment: @Qwertiy не будет заметно)

Comment: Не Диамонды, а Ромбы, наверно? )

Comment: @Kromster заменил на "ромбоносцев" )

Comment: "ромбоносец" звучит некрасиво, есть оскорбительная коннотация. Но т.к. вы из них, то дело ваше )

Comment: @Kromster я открыт к предложениям. Предлагаете просто "ромбы" написать?

Comment: Вроде бы так в обиходе они и называются. И кстати, "Основная цель ромбоносцев - указать модераторов на сайте" - тут точно ромбы.

Comment: А чего перевод до сих пор не подхватился?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ не дёрнули рубильник.

Comment: всё ещё дёргать надо...

Comment: @αλεχολυτ хотя есть вероятность, что там хардкод)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ выкатили-таки -.-